# Label to the right side of the tkinter window

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, justify, layout-anchor

The Label: "*Right Text*" should be in the right side of the tkinter window. As highlighted in image.

[image]

For that I tried below code, but its not on the right.

```
m_root = Tk()
m_root.wm_state('zoomed')

label_time = Label(m_root, text="Right Text", anchor="e", justify="right").grid()

m_root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Read about the layout managers in Tkinter, [for example](https://zetcode.com/tkinter/layout/#:~:text=Tkinter%20has%20three%20built%2Din,in%20a%20two%20dimensional%20grid.). Your problem is wrong grid function.

Comment: There are multiple ways to do it. The right way depends on what else is going in the window.  Do you really want a window with just a single label on the right, or will the window have other things? How are you adding the other widgets (`pack`? `grid`?)

Comment: @BryanOakley only single label in right, and other labels also use grid

Answer (score 0):

`label_time.pack(side="right",anchor="n")` This might work. anchor positions the text to the top-right corner.